# Tabbar hiding behind Scrollview

Tags: ios, xcode

In a UIViewcontroller I took a scrollview and a tabbar at bottom, when I run the application tabbar is hiding. Please suggest me some solutions. For UIViewcontroller I used Freeform.

Comment: Can you show your code please, so we can help you in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 44, 0);
```